# How to join data of two vectors efficiently in java me?

Tags: java, vector, java-me

I have two Vectors in my program and I want to join their data

```
Vector a=new Vector();
Vector b=new Vector();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "join?"

Comment: Pass data from A to B and generate  Vector C for example

Comment: I think @LucasRoss means how to generate Vector C (what will Vector C contain? All the elements in A followed by all the elements in B? Or will each element in C be the result of some operation of the corresponding element in A and B?).

Comment: All elements in A followed by all in B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vector a = new Vector();
Vector b = new Vector();

// populate vectors a and b
// ...

Vector c = new Vector();

for(Enumeration e = a.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    c.addElement(e.nextElement());
}
for(Enumeration e = b.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    c.addElement(e.nextElement());
}

// c now contains all elements from a followed by all elements from b
```

Comment: Good i did not think about using Enumeration like this

Comment: Any particular reason why you un-accepted this answer? Did it not work?  How can we improve on it?

Comment: I compare other answer, your answer is good and efficient, thanks Tonio

Comment: Thanks!  Although now I understand even less why you UN-accepted the answer, after having accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

The above is safe and nice. If you are a bit of performance freak, you can also try more low-level solution. By subclassing Vector you gain access to Vector's fields, so you can do:

```
NakedVector a = new NakeVector();
NakedVector b = new NakeVector();

// populate a, b 

NakedVector c = new NakedVector(a, b);

class NakedVector extends Vector {

    public NakedVector() {
        super();
    }

    ...

    public NakedVector(NakedVector a, NakedVector b) {
        elementData = new Object[a.size() + b.size()]; // or: super(a.size() + b.size());
        elementCount = elementData.length;
        System.arraycopy(a.elementData, 0, elementData, 0, a.size());
        System.arraycopy(b.elementData, 0, elementData, a.size(), b.size());
    }
}
```